# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Must specify the driver container image

Tags: apache-spark, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to do spark-submit on minikube(Kubernetes) from local machine CLI with command

```
spark-submit --master k8s://https://127.0.0.1:8001 --name cfe2 
--deploy-mode cluster --class com.yyy.Test --conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 local://spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have a simple spark job jar built on verison 2.3.0. I also have containerized it in docker and minikube up and running on virtual box.
Below is exception stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Must specify the driver container image at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.steps.BasicDriverConfigurationStep$$anonfun$3.apply(BasicDriverConfigurationStep.scala:51) at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.steps.BasicDriverConfigurationStep$$anonfun$3.apply(BasicDriverConfigurationStep.scala:51) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)  at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.steps.BasicDriverConfigurationStep.<init>(BasicDriverConfigurationStep.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.DriverConfigOrchestrator.getAllConfigurationSteps(DriverConfigOrchestrator.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2585)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
      at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 2018-04-06 13:33:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called 2018-04-06 13:33:52 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-6da93408-88cb-4fc7-a2de-18ed166c3c66
```

Comment: If you're using the command as you've written, you have a line break in between.

Answer (score 6):

Look like bug with default value for parameters `spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image`, that must be `spark.kubernetes.container.image`. So try specify driver/executor container image directly:

- spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image
- spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image

Comment: `spark-submit --master k8s://https://127.0.0.1:8001 --name cfe2  --deploy-mode cluster --class cluster com.oracle.Test --conf spark.executor.instances 2 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.docker.image docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.docker.image docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 --conf spark.kubernetes.initcontainer.docker.image docker.io/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 local://spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`    **also gives same error(same stack trace)**

Answer (score 2):

From the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/Config.scala), the only available conf options are:

```
spark.kubernetes.container.image
spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image
spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image
```

And I noticed that Spark 2.3.0 has changed a lot in terms of k8s implementation compared to 2.2.0. For example, instead of specifying driver and executor separately, the official starter's guide is to use a single image given to `spark.kubernetes.container.image`.

See if this works:

```
spark-submit \
--master k8s://http://127.0.0.1:8001 \
--name cfe2 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.oracle.Test \
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken=YOUR_TOKEN \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=PATH_TO_YOUR_CERT \
local://spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The token and cert can be found on k8s dashboard. Follow the [instructions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) to make Spark 2.3.0 compatible docker images.

Comment: :changed your above code slightly   `spark-submit --master k8s://http://127.0.0.1:8001 --name cfe2 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.oracle.Test --conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=docker/anantpukale/spark_app:1.1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image=docker.io/kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image=docker.io/kubespark/spark-executor:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 local://spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` ,OUTPUT: HTTP 502 bad gateway error. Above setup behind corporate firewall. how to bypass?

Comment: user name: @wolich22 ,  I tried to do spark submit by crearting kube pod. This is ending up with **exitCode=127**. where to check application logs??

Comment: @AnantPukale If you type `kubectl cluster-info`, you can see where Kube dashboard is hosted, you can see your jobs and check logs from the dashboard.

Comment: driver pod failing with below stack 
`++ id -u
+ myuid=0
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
++ getent passwd 0
+ uidentry=root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
+ '[' -z root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash ']'
+ /sbin/tini -s -- driver
[FATAL tini (10)] exec driver failed: No such file or directory` Driver image used was docker.io/kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0

Comment: That's the error you get when using Spark 2.2.0's docker image. You need to build new image following [Spark 2.3.0's tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) using the 2.3.0's docker-image-tool.sh.

Comment: My application jar and spark-submit is happening on spark 2.3.0 . and the driver image docker.io/kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 is image given in kubespark docker hub. If i dont mention driver and executor image, it says provide driver and executor image. so i am using one given kubespark @wolich22

Comment: That is odd, because when I run the spark-submit from 2.3.0, I only needed `spark.kubernetes.container.image`, the one that I built using `docker-image-tool.sh`, instead of driver and executor separately. @AnantPukale

Comment: 1.with only spark.kubernetes.container.image, i get error on kubernetes that provide driver image. 2. Does this matter where i build my docker image? . However i can see my built image spark2.3.0 in docker daemon running in minikube.@wolich22